# author-year natbib apalike and [1], [2], [3] like numbering in the references

Tags: numbering, natbib

My dear latex-community friends. I was just curious to know if it is at all possible to get serial numbering in the list of references when I am using an apalike style bibliography. My references are working fine, though. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default,light,semibold]{sourceserifpro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{a4,amsfonts,latexsym,amscd,amsopn,amssymb,amsmath, amsthm,bbm,stmaryrd,wasysym,mathbbol}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[ruled, noend, noline]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\setlength{\topskip}{10mm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[inactive]{srcltx}           
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[scale=.95,type1]{cabin}
\usepackage[cochineal,bigdelims,cmintegrals,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[zerostyle=c,scaled=.94]{newtxtt}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{calrsfs}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\textheight 235.0mm
\textwidth 155.0mm
\topmargin -15.0mm
\oddsidemargin 2.0mm
\footskip 15.0mm
\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\raggedbottom
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\parindent0mm


\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\newcounter{mybibcounter}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\RenewDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{om}{\oldbibitem[#1]{#2} \refstepcounter{mybibcounter}\themybibcounter. }


\newcommand{\inte}[1]{%
  {\kern0pt#1}^{\mathrm{o}}%
}
\newcommand\myatop[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0, 128, 128}
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=myblue,urlcolor=myblue,citecolor=myblue,}
\newcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{myblue}}
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{myblue}(#1)}}

\def\upmodels{\perp\!\!\!\perp}
    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{ref}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really only want to add numbers to the bibliography, but keep citing with author-year citations? The numbers in the bibliography will not correspond to anything in your document in that case. In fact these numbers will distract from the name and year, which your readers need to find a citation.

Comment: If you wanted numeric citations the answer would be to replace `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` with `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`. Note that in any case, you don't need `\usepackage{cite}` if you load `natbib`.

Comment: @moewe your first comment is really a valid point though, I did not think about that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try redefining the `\bibitem` command so that it does what the old one does, but also increases a counter, something like this (at the end of the preamble):

```
\newcounter{mybibcounter}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\RenewDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{om}{\oldbibitem[#1]{#2} \refstepcounter{mybibcounter}\themybibcounter. }
```

It's hard to know if that will work properly without access to your complete document and bib file, however.

Unrelated suggestions: (1) you're loading multiple packages more than once (mathrsfs, caption with different options, setspace is loaded three different times!); you should clean out the duplicate entries, (2) you shouldn't load the cite package if you're also using natbib; natbib does everything cite does and more, and using it may cause conflicts; (3) the hyperref package should be loaded *after* other packages, so move it later in your preamble.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. And Thank you for the other suggestions!!

Comment: Could you please see my edited packages now? Are they look ok?

Comment: Another question: Right now the numbering is like 1., 2., instead of the dot after the numbering can I get [1], [2] like this? This looks better in the listing of references.

Comment: My PhD thesis has 600 references your command worked in that preamble too. Thank you, but please let me know if we can do like [1], [2], like this

Comment: You can just put whatever punctuation you want around `\themybibcounter` in the redefined command, `\RenewDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{om}{\oldbibitem[#1]{#2} \refstepcounter{mybibcounter}[\themybibcounter] }`. But I think moewe's point in the comment carries even more weight then.